# get list of selected items from select box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

i am using a multi select box in javascript as given [here](http://quasipartikel.at/2009/05/10/jqueryui-multiselect/):

i want to get the list of selected items in the multi select text box (the left list)
what can i do to achieve that?

my select box is as follows:

```
<select id="userList" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="users[]" style="width: 75px;">

//List

</select>
```

i guess `users[]` stores the selected users at a point in time. but i can't figure out how to retrieve that variable.

Comment: With JS? In an Array? Or http-query-style, like the browser sends to the server?

Comment: i didn't quite get your question. i am using javascript though

Comment: Do you want a JS array with values, or a string with http query you can send with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will work:

```
$('[name="user[]"]').val()
```

PS: You need to have jQuery included in your webpage.

from the demo at http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/, doing `$('[name="countries[]"]').val()` will give sample output:

```
["ARM", "AUS", "AUT"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of values with jQuery:

```
var values = $select.find('option:checked').map(function() {
  return this.value || this.text;
});
// or $select.val() of course, like lemarc says
// => ['ABC', 'DEF']

var prefix = encodeURIComponent($select.attr('name')) + '=';
var httpQuery = values.length ? prefix + values.map(function() {
  return encodeURIComponent(this);
}).join('&' + prefix);
// => users[]=ABC&users[]=DEF
```

I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

This will return array of selected values

```
$('#userList').val();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zUSeg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly target ***$(".multiselect")*** Object, by doing this:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    _selValue = $(".multiselect").val(); //You will have variable of selected values
    for(var i=0;i<_selValue.length;i++){
        alert(_selValue[i]);
        //You can iterate it individually in loop
    }
});
```